# How to do nested queries in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is `answerModel` in short. I am not getting expected results. I want some help knowing how to perform nested find queries using mongoose

```
"question_id": {
    "topics": [
        "curium"
    ],
    "_id": "5edb42f9a0b1c85754d6ca24",
    "questionText": "What actually is curium",
    "id": "5edb42f9a0b1c85754d6ca24"
}
```

and here's schema definition:

```
const answerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    question_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Questions',
        required: [true,'Answer must belongs to particular question']
    }
})
```

and I'm also using query middleware to populate before find query

```
answerSchema.pre(/^find/, function (next) {
    console.log('Populating answer schem')
    this.populate({
        path: 'question_id',
        select: 'questionText topics'
    });
    next();
})

console.log(req.params.topicaName);        // curium
const answers = await answerModel.find({'question_id.topics': req.params.topicaName });
console.log('answers are', answers)   // answers are []
```

and I am getting this output to console:

```
curium
Populating answer schem
answers are []
```

Comment: Please add the schema definition for `answerModel` to your question.

Comment: @Molda please help

Comment: Don't use the `answerSchema.pre`. Use something like this instead `answerModel.find().populate({ path: 'question_id', match: { topics: { $eq: req.params.topicaName }}`

Comment: I already written so much code with mongoose query middleware. Now I can't remove it. Can you please tell me some other way

Comment: I don't think there's another way. And i think it was bad idea to add the `.pre` for every find query in the first place. Now when you only want a list of answers it will always populate question even when you don't need it. It's also bad for performance.

Comment: How does it populate pre-find?  At that point there is nothing to look up